# slideToggle() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<li>` in which are TWO `<ul>`.The second `<ul>` is hidden and should be shown when i click inside the first `<ul>`.

I've tried this : `$(me).parent().parent().find("ul").slideToggle();`
$(me) is an instance of this and the `<li>` Wrapper-Element.

The Problem is now that the hidden `<ul>` is shown but the visible `<ul>` hides.
And it should not hide that.I want the hidden `<ul>` to show and hide right when i am clicking on the visible `<ul>`.

Another thing to mention is that i am using this code in an success function of an ajax call :

```
success:function(data){
     $(me).parent().parent().find("ul").slideToggle();
}
```

Maybe someone can help me.I probaply just need to adjust the `.find()` but i dont know how to do it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS child selectors in jQuery.  The following fiddle demonstrates that if you click inside the first UL, the second will slide.

```
$('li ul:first-child li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("ul:nth-child(2)").slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mqjvt2nu/2/

There are a bunch of ways to do this.  You can specify classes or id's and target that way.  You can use the [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function in jQuery.  You could also use the [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) or [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .not method:

```
$(me).parent().parent().find("ul").not(':visible').slideToggle();
```